# How to prevent state increment/decrement counter going below 1

Tags: reactjs, state

Morning all,

I'm sure the solution to this is very simple, I am trying to prevent my quantity counter from going below 1, however due to the state it will go into negative figures if i keep decrementing it. Does anyone know how to resolve this? Thanks a lot in advance, let me know if I am being unclear here.

Happy new year!

Thanks!

```js
class FormQuantity extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      counter: 1
    };
  }

  increment = () => {
    this.setState({
      counter: this.state.counter + 1
    });
  };

  decrement = () => {
    this.setState({
      counter: this.state.counter - 1
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
        <div className="form-quantity">
        
          <button
              className="btn"
              onClick={this.decrement}>
              <span>&minus;</span>
            </button>

            <span className="form-quantity__counter">{this.state.counter}</span>
            
            <button
              className="btn"
              onClick={this.increment}>
              <span>&#43;</span>
            </button>
            
            
        </div>
    );
  }
}

export default FormQuantity;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Just add a check in decrement function for counter value equality to 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Meir answer works perfectly. Here I am using the `Math.max` method as used by @Meir with fewer codes.

So, there is only one function which does both increment and decrement and also checks the negative value.

```js
toggleValue = (value) => {
  this.setState({
    counter: Math.max(0, value)
  })
}

  render() {
    let {counter} = this.state
    return (
        <div className="form-quantity">
          <button
              className="btn"
              onClick={() => this.toggleValue(counter-1)}>
              <span>&minus;</span>
            </button>
            <span className="form-quantity__counter">{counter}</span>            
            <button
              className="btn"
              onClick={() => this.toggleValue(counter+1)}>
              <span>&#43;</span>
            </button>
            
            
        </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Here is the live [demo](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/yGPPpV)

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Big fan on this, I will use this example as less code, thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

You have 2 ways of doing this, and the best solution probably involves both:

In your decrement function check the value:

```
decrement = () => {
  this.setState({
    counter: Math.max(0, this.state.counter - 1)
  });
};
```

Disable the decrement button when you can not decrement:

```
<button
    className="btn"
    onClick={this.decrement}
    disabled={this.state.counter <= 1}
>
    <span>&minus;</span>
</button>
```

The first one is about good practices and having a safe component (i.e. you can not do an illegal/illogical action). The second is good UI practices, the user can not do these actions and the visuals indicated this.

Comment: Thank you very much for this, that's perfect. Will mark as correct answer when I can!

Answer (score 0):

I checked if the count was equal to 1, if it was return, that seemed to work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `prevState` in **setState** to check this and update state accordingly.

**Increment :**

```
increment = () => {
        this.setState(prevState => ({    
                isToggleOn: prevState.counter >= 1 ? prevState.counter + 1 : prevState.counter;
        }));
      };
```

**Decrement :**

```
decrement = () => {
    this.setState(prevState => ({    
            isToggleOn: prevState.counter >= 1 ? prevState.counter - 1 : prevState.counter;
    }));
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

```
constructor(){
  super()
  this.state = {
    counter: 0
  }
}

toggleValue = () => {
  this.setState(prevState => 
    ({counter: prevState.counter}))
}

  render() {
    let {counter} = this.state
    return (
        <div className="form-quantity">
          {partsInt(this.state.counter) > 0 ? <button
              className="btn"
              onClick={() => this.toggleValue(counter-1)}>
              <span>&minus;</span>
            </button> : ''}
            <span className="form-quantity__counter">{counter}</span>            
            <button
              className="btn"
              onClick={() => this.toggleValue(counter+1)}>
              <span>&#43;</span>
            </button>
        </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Here I have didn't shown the button for decrement the number.. And its value is greater than or equal to 1, and then it will be visible to add.